# Is there polynomial algorithm to this? Possibly dynamic programming approach?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Assume you are given a set *A* = {1, 2, ..., *m*} and a set *B* = {1, 2, ..., *n*}, such that **each element from the set *A* has to be assigned to some element from *B***. The following parameters for each element *i* from the set *A* and each element *j* from the set *B* are known:

- *S<sub>ij</sub>* is the cost of assignment an element *i* to element *j* greater or equal to zero;
- *t<sub>ij</sub>* is the minimal preference of element *i* to element *j*  greater or equal to zero;
- *T<sub>ij</sub>* is the maximal preference of element *i* to element *j*  greater or equal to zero.

For each fixed *i*, all values of *t<sub>ij</sub>*, *T<sub>ij</sub>* (for all *j*'s) are different. *m* and *n* are integers greater than 0, and the other variables are non-negative real numbers.

Elements from the set *A* are assigned to elements from *B* according to their preferences *t<sub>ij</sub>* (or *T<sub>ij</sub>*). For example, if *t<sub>ij</sub>* < *t<sub>ik</sub>* (preferences *T<sub>ij</sub>* or *T<sub>ik</sub>* might be used in any case instead, read further), then element *i* will be assigned to *j* rather then *k*. Out of *mn* preferences, exactly *r* of them have to use value of *T<sub>ij</sub>* as a value of preference, and remaining *mn - r* have to use value of *t<sub>ij</sub>* (which is lower value then *T<sub>ij</sub>*).

If element *i* is assigned to an element *j*, then the cost *S<sub>ij</sub>* is added to the total cost of assignment to element *j*, i.e., *C<sub>j</sub>* = *C<sub>j</sub>* + *S<sub>ij</sub>*. Let *Max* be the maximum among all costs *C<sub>j</sub>* and *Min* the minimum among all costs *C<sub>j</sub>*. The goal is to choose which preferences of assignment element *i* to element *j* will take the value of *T<sub>ij</sub>*, and which preferences will take the value of *t<sub>ij</sub>*, such that the value of:

1. *Max* is minimal;
2. *Max - Min* is minimal.

I think there is some dynamic programming algorithm, but I'm not sure. Does anybody know how to solve this by DP approach, or any other? It might not be polynomial, however, but I think it is.

**Example.** Let *m* = 3, *n* = 2, i.e. *A* = {1, 2, 3} and *B* = {1, 2, 3}. Let *r* = 2, and matrices *S*, *t* and *T* be given as

```
    |5 9|      |1 3|      |10  7|
S = |7 1|, t = |4 2|, T = | 5  4|.
    |8 4|      |3 4|      | 9 12|
```

**Solution is equal to 5** in the case of minimizing the value of *Max*. Similar example might be constructed for minimizing *Max* - *Min*.

Comment: I smell some flavor of bin packing in the problem statement. Thus, not sure if the algorithm can be polynomial

Comment: You might not be able to optimize *Max* and *Max - Min* at the same time. Are those different goals or do you use *Max - Min* only as a tie breaker for solutions with the same *Max*?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. These are two different problems. First one is to minimize *Max*, and the second one to minimize *Max - Min*.

Comment: So you say you do `m*n` assignments. Which means every element of A is assigned to *all* elements in B. What am I misunderstanding? I think an example would greatly help this question.

Comment: Also, what are the range restrictions for all of your variables (`n`, `m`, `r`, `S_ij`, `t_ij`, `T_ij`)? Are they all integers? Greater than zero? How large can they be at max? You need to be more specific on those points.

Comment: There are *m* assignments, again mistake, there are *mn* preferences *tij* (or *Tij*).

Comment: n, m, and r are integers, where r <= mn, and the other are real variables.

Comment: How large are `n` and `m`? Please consider adding an example.

Comment: *n* and *m* are greater or equal then 1. (If that restriction might help, one may suppose *n* > *m*, or even *n* >> *m*, but I think it's not that important). I will add example. Or real variables are greater or equal than zero. (Also, if that might help, we can say that all values t_ij and T_ij are different.)

Comment: @user3372185: I meant upper bounds for `n` and `m`.

Comment: Upper bounds, n <= 5000 and m <= 500.

Comment: Don't care about upper bounds of *n* and *m*, any polynomial algorithm would be enough.

Comment: have you thought about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem ?

Comment: Why all the preferences? Couldn't this problem be restated with each element of A having two choices of assignments in set B, instead of a ton of preferences that mostly don't matter?

Comment: @user2357112: Yep, only the argmin of t_ij and T_ij matter for fixed i.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is NP-hard, which can be shown by reducing [Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) to it.

Let's assume we have an algorithm *M* that solves your problem optimally.

We are given a Partition instance *X* = {*x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>m</sub>*} and want to find a partition of *S* into two subsets with minimum sum difference. Let's define *n = 2, S<sub>ij</sub> = x<sub>i</sub>, t<sub>ij</sub> = -j, T<sub>ij</sub> = j*. Now we just iterate over all possible *r* and call *M* as a subroutine to find the global minimum for *Max*. We can show that the assignment that results in the minimum *Max* is an optimal 2-partition of *X*.

Since you're not working with integer costs but with real costs and since your problem is likely to get harder for *n > 2* (we can also reduce [Bin packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) with *n* bins to your problem in a straight-forward way), it seems highly unlikely that there exists even a pseudopolyonomial solution for your problem unless *P = NP*. You should consider using heuristics to get a good approximative solution. A good starting point would be to look at the approximation schemes for Bin packing and try to adapt them to your problem. Maybe a simple first-fit approach is enough for your needs. Two more things you should keep in mind:

- You can binary search for *Max* and then use it as a fixed upper bound for your "bins"
- *t<sub>ij</sub>* and *T<sub>ij</sub>* can be reduced to their respective argmins for a fixed *i*. You have a set of preferences *T<sub>i,1</sub>* (extracted from  *t<sub>ij</sub>*) and an alternative set of preferences *T<sub>i,2</sub>* (extracted from  *T<sub>ij</sub>*) for every *i*. No point even considering the non-minimal preferences.